# Continue drawing line in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomjerry25/jnme6vy7/) which creates a pattern of 4 points.

What I want is for it to continuously draw the projected line until the user click for point B, then point C and D.

```
function draw(){

//
ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

// draw connecting lines
for(var i=0;i<connectors.length;i++){
    var c=connectors[i];
    var s=anchors[c.start];
    var e=anchors[c.end];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(s.x,s.y);
    ctx.lineTo(e.x,e.y);
    ctx.stroke();
}   

// draw circles
for(var i=0;i<anchors.length;i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(anchors[i].x,anchors[i].y,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill(); 
    ctx.fillText(anchors[i].label,anchors[i].x-5,anchors[i].y-15); 
}

}
```

Comment: So you want to discontinue when the user clicks point B and start all another connection point

Comment: What I want is for the line to show up (projected lines) for each point. The final result will not be altered.

Comment: So you want preview lines while mousemoving (presumably in another color?)

Comment: @JT_25 if it's not answered in a few hours i'll answer it, don't have the time right now. Basically all you need to do is keep track of the current point (and would be connectors, since in some cases it's 2) in a separate array, and draw them at the end of your drawing function in a different color.

Comment: @DrunkWolf no worries :)

Comment: @JT_25 i have looked a bit at your code in the meantime, and i 'fixed' your anchor adding function to go on forever at least :P I'll probably post an answer with you wanted in a bit :)

Comment: @DrunkWolf is it possible also to for example start with  letter 'S' then 'A','B','C', 'D' ?

Comment: @Kaiido A to B is working but when you add point C the projection of A to C is not working.

Comment: @JT_25 yes that's possible, instead of taking the letters from charcode, define your own array with letters to be used. For instance, you could do lettering = ['S','A','B','C'] and take letters like letter = lettering[i%4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, basically you need your connector adding function to be slightly smarter, so we can make this work like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drunkwolf/uxetsmxp/1/)

(You were adding way to many connectors, and it stopped at length over 7, this fixes both those)

```
    if(draggingIndex==-1 && fullDrag == null){
        addAnchor(startX,startY);
        var al = anchors.length-1;
        var almod4 = al%4;
        if(almod4==1){
            connectors.push({start:al-1,end:al});
        }
        if(almod4==2){
            connectors.push({start:al-2,end:al});
            connectors.push({start:al-1,end:al});
        }
        if(almod4==3){
            connectors.push({start:al-2,end:al});
            connectors.push({start:al-1,end:al});
        }
        draw();
    }
```

As you can see, based on the value of anchors.length-1 modular 4, we know if we need to draw 1 or 2 lines. In our draw function we can then add:

```
 if (anchors.length>0 && anchors.length%4>0){
       ctx.strokeStyle='gray';
       var al = anchors.length-1;
       var almod4 = al%4;
       if (almod4==1 || almod4==2){
       //draw extra line
           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.moveTo(anchors[al-1].x,anchors[al-1].y);
           ctx.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
           ctx.stroke();
       }
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.moveTo(anchors[al].x,anchors[al].y);
       ctx.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
       ctx.stroke();
    }
```

Note that instead of checking for almod4 being 2 or 3, we check for 1 and 2, because that means we're in the process of adding 2 or 3.

Now all you need to do is tell it to draw at every mouseover, and voila, preview lines.